# Calculate and add no of views dynamically to tableView row swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview

i need to design below screen.

[image]

i have taken dynamic tableview. Inside the tableview i have taken two views

```
---> one view contains a label - used to display month name
---> second View contains two labels which is in the above screen 
i got problem with the second view. i have taken two labels in second view

second View-->
--> belowLabel: displaying the date of the Jan (ex: 5 )
--> aboveLabel: the no of visits on 5th jan
if January contains 6 days visits, then i need to display that no of secondviews(dynamically)
```

I am displaying the no of rows as per no of months. but how to show dynamically views inside the table view row??

Comment: You can use stackView or else you can use collectionview inside the tableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

yo can use a UICollection View to achive this with a personilized colectionView Cell